# ES6 calling method in another class, using modules

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I know there is many questions like this asked, but I have been searching for hours and can't find any answers. I have this method, which takes in a parameter, which should be ID of two selects. Using this parameter, I want to determine which select is used and execute the if statement, but to no avail. When I run it, it shows no errors in console in Chrome and it does nothing. Can anyone shed some light on it, this is the method in one export class:

```
static styleCircle(select) {
    if(this.select === ELEMENTS.ELEMENT_COLOR_SELECT) {
      var getColor = ELEMENTS.ELEMENT_COLOR_SELECT;
      var colorValue = getColor.options[getColor.selectedIndex].value;
      ELEMENTS.ELEMENT_STYLE_CIRCLE.style.backgroundColor = colorValue;
    } else if(select == ELEMENTS.ELEMENT_BORDER_SELECT) {
      var getRadius = ELEMENTS.ELEMENT_BORDER_SELECT;
      var radiusValue = getRadius.options[getRadius.selectedIndex].value;
      ELEMENTS.ELEMENT_STYLE_CIRCLE.style.borderRadius = radiusValue;
    }
  }
```

This is it being called in another class, on two select elements, and the class is imported at the top of the file:

```
ELEMENTS.ELEMENT_COLOR_SELECT.onchange = Script.styleCircle(this);
ELEMENTS.ELEMENT_BORDER_SELECT.onchange = Script.styleCircle(this);
```

ELEMENTS is a file with constants, which are just being used to get ID's from the HTML file. I used other methods like this, with onclick events, but none had parameters, and now I'm stuck here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should consider using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of the old-school "on*" properties.

Comment: You are checking `this.select` in the first if, you probably meant just `select`.

Comment: I tried using addEventListener, still the same issue.
Yes, my mistake, just select.

Comment: @LeonGrubisic concerning your last edit, please read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106812/251777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to call the functions right now but instead you probably want to pass functions. Through that you can access the proper `this` and pass it to `styleCircle`:

```
ELEMENTS.ELEMENT_COLOR_SELECT.onchange = function() {
   Script.styleCircle(this);
};

ELEMENTS.ELEMENT_BORDER_SELECT.onchange =  function() {
  Script.styleCircle(this);
};
```

Additionally `this.select` is probably causing you troubles as `window.select` is `undefined`.

Comment: I removed the this. from the select and added an else with console log. I tried your line of code, and when I select from the dropdown it goes to the else part and prints it out, it won't compare.

Comment: THANK YOU. It works now. If you were near me I'd buy you a beer.

Comment: @leon glad to help :) (and no worries, I got enough beer in the fridge ;))

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to try debugging and ensure `select` is equivalent to either of those constants. Make sure you have full branching coverage in your debugging. That would mean start by adding an `else` statement to that `if/else if` statement - it's possible that your select is not equal to either constant and so neither branch is run.

Comment: I added an     else to it, and console log in it, and when I reload the page it is printed right away, without selecting the select element.

Comment: Ah it also looks like you may need to use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) for these onChange events:
`ELEMENTS.ELEMENT_COLOR_SELECT.onchange = Script.styleCircle.bind(this);
ELEMENTS.ELEMENT_BORDER_SELECT.onchange = Script.styleCircle.bind(this);`